# Jquery show / hide fix

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I need fix this little code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.plus').click(function(){
        $('#top:hidden').show('slow');
        $('.plus').click(function(){
            $('#top:visible').hide('slow');

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: And what's wrong with it? Please explain what you want the code to do, and what it actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to bind click twice, rather you can put condition to show and hide.

```
$('.plus').click(function(){
    if($('#top').is(':visible')
         $('#top').hide('slow');
   else
         $('#top').show('slow');        
});
```

You can also use [toogle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

```
$('.plus').toggle(function(){
      $('#top').show('slow');
},  
function(){
       $('#top').hide('slow');
});
```

Comment: Not that the `.toggle()` reference that you linked to is for the animation method, not for the [`.toggle()` event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function that you actually used...

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.plus').click(function(){
        $('#top').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

That is, each time the `'.plus'` element is clicked, the `'#top'` element will be [toggled](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) between visible and invisible.

The code as shown in the question says that when `'.plus'` is clicked, make `'#top'` visible (if it is currently not) and then assign a second click handler that will make `'#top'` invisible. On the next click both of these handlers will run, creating a *third* handler. On the next click all three handlers run. And so forth. That is, repeated calls to `.click()` add additional handlers, they don't replace previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle()` to replace `hide()` and `show()`

```
$('.plus').click(function(){
   $('#top').toggle('slow');
})
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/